# Passing metadata in a context

Tags: android, facebook, metadata, android-context

In the latest Facebook SDK (3.0) there is a check in the Session constructor that attempts to pull an application ID from the metadata associated with context/package/application.

```
ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if (ai.metaData != null) {
            System.out.println("So depressed " + ai.metaData.getString(APPLICATION_ID_PROPERTY));
            return ai.metaData.getString(APPLICATION_ID_PROPERTY);
        }
```

If this data is null the Session constructor fails and a null pointer error is thrown.

In the activity that instantiates the Session object I attempt to populate this metadata:

```
ai = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                    this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            if (ai.metaData != null) {
                ai.metaData.putString(Session.APPLICATION_ID_PROPERTY, AppConfig.getFacebookAppId()+"");
            }
```

I have verified that before I attempt to instantiate the Session object that the metadata is appropriately set. However, inside the method that Session calls from its constructor the metadata is null.

Two things I know: the memory address for the context is the same, so it appears to be the same object. However the memory address for

```
this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                        this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

appears to be different. I am not sure if that has any meaning.

My ultimate question is can this metadata be passed around like this? If so what is failing here?

Comment: Solved: You can't do it that way above. What you can do is but the value in your manifest in a metadata tag.

`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebookAppId" />`

Comment: This is correct. If you already have the app id available in code, then you can just pass it in via the Session.Builder. The meta-data is only a convenience mechanism.

Comment: @BrianTompsett If you're going to resurrect questions from three years ago you should fix *everything* in the post (like the bad code formatting), not just remove "Thanks".

Answer (score -4):

The OP wrote:

> You can't do it that way above. What you can do is but the value in your manifest in a metadata tag. `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebookAppId" />`

@Ming Li wrote:

> This is correct. If you already have the app id available in code, then you can just pass it in via the Session.Builder. The meta-data is only a convenience mechanism.

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)

Comment: If you're going to repost comments as answers you should clean up the quality - fix typos, formatting, etc.

Comment: @AndrewMedico. Thanks for the note. This edit was [discussed in meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297193/4370109) as part of a tag deprecation. All were done carefully as reported in my meta answer.